# Inverse of a multivalued function

Tags: inverse

I try to get the inverse of a simple function like `x^2,x≥0`. Still, when I use InverseFunction Mathematica gives me back `-(y^0.5)` which is indeed an inverse, but for x≤0:

```
InverseFunction[#^2 &]
```

> InverseFunction::ifun: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses.
>
> -Sqrt[#1] &

I know I could just fix the problem putting a minus before InverseFunction. But is there a way to choose which of the inverse function I can get back, when I deal with a non-injective function like `x^2`? In other words, which is the option so that InverseFunction gives me back `(y^0.5)` instead fo `-(y^0.5)`?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression) to control which branch [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction) uses:

```
InverseFunction @ Function[x, ConditionalExpression[x^2, x<0]]
InverseFunction @ Function[x, ConditionalExpression[x^2, x>0]]
```

> Function[x, ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[x], x >= 0]]
>
> Function[x, ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[x], x >= 0]]

Comment: Can we find all possible inverse of a function? For example, how can we find all inverse functions of `(2^(x-1)-1)/x`?